# Why doesn't Excel/VBA show the 'BLACK LARGE CIRCLE' sign?

Tags: vba, unicode

Why doesn't ChrW accept 'BLACK LARGE CIRCLE' (U+2B24) on my system (see
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b24/index.htm)? Only thing I see is an empty squares (◻)...

I tried this:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = ChrW(9608) 'works fine, gives 'FULL BLOCK' (U+2588)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = ChrW(9608) 'works fine, gives 'BLACK CIRCLE' (U+25CF)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = ChrW(11044) 'does not work, should give 'BLACK LARGE CIRCLE' (U+2B24)
```

My system is Windows 7 and I'm using MSO 2007.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. :-) Please take the time to properly format code in your questions in the future; it makes them much easier to read and understand. You can format it in several ways: Select it all and either click the `{}` button on the toolbar of the text area or press `Ctrl+K`, or you can simply indent each code line by 4 or more space characters. For small code sections in the text, just surround it with backticks. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CharW is accepting the Unicode U+2B24 character correctly, but you are using a font that doesn't have a [glyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) defined for U+2B24.

Assuming you are using the default Arial, if you run Character Map you will see that Arial does not have any glyphs defined for anything between U+266F and U+2C60.

Any undefined Unicode character is displayed as a block,which is what you are seeing.  If you want to use U+2B24 you will have to find a font that has a glyph defined for that code point.

Comment: The Fileformat.info page mentioned in the question contains the link [Fonts that support U+2B24](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b24/fontsupport.htm). The list there is a good starting point, though not necessarily exhaustive. None of the fonts listed there is shipped with Windows or Office, but they are freeware (except for Code2000, which has obscure status) and can be found by following links there or with some googling.

Comment: Thanks, I see now where my issue is.
I'm trying to build a small dashboard presentation without any additional graphic items (only fonts) and would need the bullet for traffic lights.
But I can not accept installing any additional fonts for applying this small app on customer PC's.
I'll have to stick with 'BLACK CIRCLE' (U+25CF) and increase the font size. This will give the needed traffic light, but has other drawbacks e.g. making the Excel rows larger.